# Which can be used for data transfer on Destiny?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, destiny, xbox-one

I know that you can transfer your data in Destiny from Xbox 360 and Xbox One, but I have two question for this transfer:

1. Can you go back and forth for this transfer? ex. playing Xbox One and your data will go back to the Xbox 360 in case you wanna play Destiny on the 360 with friends.
2. Do you have to buy the game on disc or download it from the Xbox store for the transfer to work?

Comment: I can't answer with specifics but as I understand it you don't need to do anything special except for sign in on the appropriate system with your appropriate XBL account. I doubt it matters whether you have a download or disc. I don't know if you can keep going back and forth or if the change is a one time thing. I'd assume the former but there might be technical reasons why it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

The data doesn't live on Xbox One or Xbox 360, it lives on Bungie servers, connected to your Xbox Live account.

So yes, you can go back and forth, but it is not a transfer.

As such, all you have to do is start the game on either of the two platforms and your characters and everything will be there, ready to play.

This is also true for PS3 and PS4, the characters and your Destiny data is tied to your PSN account, on Bungie servers.

You do need to have purchased the game on both console generations though, so in order to play on both Xbox 360 and Xbox One you need to purchase the game for both Xbox 360 and Xbox One. Same goes for PS3 and PS4, you need to purchase it for both PS3 and PS4.

Whether you have a digital game downloaded from the respective store, or a store-bought game on disc doesn't matter one bit as the data is stored on Bungie servers tied to your account. This is not necessarily true for other games, but for Destiny it is. You can even mix and match, having a disc-based Destiny for Xbox 360, and a digital only Destiny for Xbox One.

Comment: Adding to your statement that you do need to purchase the game on both console generations, Bungie is currently having a [free Destiny digital upgrade offer](http://www.destinythegame.com/digital-upgrade) where you get the digital Xbox One version free if you own the Xbox 360 digital version (and same for PlayStation).